# Why is the FeathersJS auth hooks never invoked?

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I have the following piece of code which sets up 4 hooks for my FeathersJS service:

```
 service.before({
      all: [
    auth.verifyToken(),
    auth.populateUser(),
    auth.restrictToAuthenticated(),
    myCustomHook()
]});
```

The last hook is invoked so I know my code works right overall.

However, the three auth-hooks does not seem to be called, which is what puzzles me. Any suggestions to why this could happen or how I can debug it will be appreciated.

*** More details: ***

I'm inside a unittest and all I do is this:

```
app.service('/blockAddresses').find({})
```

I would expect a failure coming from the auth.restrictToAuthenticated hook. I see no such failure and therefore I conclude that the auth-hooks are never invoked. Of course, this conclusion might be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `verifyToken` hook will be skipped if the request did not come through the REST or Socket.io API. It checks for `params.provider` being set. In a unit test I usually just pass a test `{ user }` in `params` but if you want to verify a token you can set the provider and token like this:

```
app.service('/blockAddresses').find({
  provider: 'test',
  token: 'myinvalidtoken'
})
```

Comment: Great thx, I didn't now this. Will have a fresh look at it and for now mark it as the correct answer.